# tt_news single view with static news_id

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I am using Typo3 Version 6.2 with the plugin tt_news.

All I want to do is:

- Have a simple page on my website
- On that page I want to have a tt_news single view
- the news_id of this view should be static (set by me) and NOT by GET variables

Use Case:

We have a company with many departments. For every department we have a couple of subpages on our website. Now I want to add specific news to each of those department websites. Like: On the team management page I want to show the news with ID = XY.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: You can use list view plugin. Limit just 1 item in list. Show full text of item in list and show item from specific category. One item - one category and just one item in list plugin tt_news)

Comment: Could you switch to the [News system](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news) extension? It's based on Extbase and Fluid and does have this feature right away. You can even [migrate from tt_news](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Migration/MigrationFromTtNews/Index.html).

Comment: @OlegVKarun But can I specify the news element within the specific category? Or will it only select the _latest_ oder _oldest_ element of this category?

Comment: @zarathustra I meen just one category for one item. And this way you can specify. But this very craftily. It is beter to use solution from the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the following lines to the setup field of an ext-template at the page where you want to display the selected news item in SINGLE view if no SINGLE view for another record was requested:

```
# hide the "no news id" message
plugin.tt_news._LOCAL_LANG.default.noNewsIdMsg = &nbsp;
# set the tt_news singlePid to the current page
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = 977

# fill the content of the main-column to a tmp.object
tmp.pagecontent < page.10.subparts.contentarea

# clear the content of the main column
page.10.subparts.contentarea >

# build a new object for this column as content-object-array
page.10.subparts.contentarea = COA
page.10.subparts.contentarea {
  10 = CONTENT
  10.table = tt_news
  10.select {
# insert the pids of all pages from where you want to fetch news.
# the recursive-field has no influence on this selection
    pidInList = 25 # your pid
    # orderBy = datetime desc
    max = 1
   # get element with news id 10 @zarathustra
   where = tt_news.uid=10
  }
# insert the object “10.” only if there is no SINGLE news selected
  10.stdWrap.if.isFalse.data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|tt_news
# re-insert the normal pagecontent to the page
  20 < tmp.pagecontent
}
```

More information here 
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/3.5.1/ExtNews/Configuration/TyposcriptExamples/Index.html#default-news-id

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer but it is not working - in fact nothing has changed. "no news id" is still displayed. I changed `page.10.subparts.contentarea` to `page.10.variables.news` to adopt this script to my site. But nothing is happening.

Comment: It must be problem in "page.10.subparts.content"/ You should check your subparts in ts config. In comment they have the same problem http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/28686/?tx_mmforum_pi1%5BshowForm%5D=0&cHash=963ffc54b6f12b9f1463203aecf68756

Comment: Okay, now I got something, **but** where can I specify the news id? Right now, just the latest news element is displayed.

Comment: I changed the answer and added "where = tt_news.uid=10", so it perfectly fits my problem.